# Replace value in cookie ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-authentication, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm using the cookie middleware in ASP.NET Core 1.0 without ASP.NET Identity - as described in this article:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html

When a user makes certain changes to his/her profile, I need to change some values in the cookie. In such scenarios, this article tells me to

> call context.ReplacePrincipal() and set the context.ShouldRenew flag
>   to true

How exactly do I do that? I think the article is referring to HttpContext. I don't see a ReplacePrincipal() method under HttpContext.

I'd appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

Comment: From the article, `context` looks like it's a `CookieValidatePrincipalContext`.

Comment: How do I access the methods of CookieValidatePrincipalContext? I've been doing some research on this since you gave me the answer but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNet/Authentication/Cookies/CookieValidatePrincipalContext/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the article they are referencing the `CookieValidatePrincipalContext` from the `OnValidatePrincipal` delegate in the `CookieAuthenticationEvents` options.

You have to wire it up in the `app.UseCookieAuthentication` function in `startup.cs` like so:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
     //other options here
     options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
     {
          OnValidatePrincipal = UpdateValidator.ValidateAsync
     };     
 });
```

And the `UpdateValidator` function would look like:

```
public static class UpdateValidator
{
    public static async Task ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        //check for changes to profile here

        //build new claims pricipal.
        var newprincipal = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal();

        // set and renew
        context.ReplacePrincipal(newprincipal);
        context.ShouldRenew = true;
    }
}
```

There is a good example in the `SecurityStampValidator`  class which you can find on github: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Identity/SecurityStampValidator.cs