# Possible to persist additional claims on ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using asp.net core/OpenIdConnect/Cookies authentication.

I can add custom claims to the ClaimsIdentity in the TokenValidated event and these persist fine.

However there is an additional code path when I can only add the claims to the ClaimsIdentity as part of a Controller POST action.
However these additional claims are not persisted and lost for the next request.

Is this actually possible to get these claims persisted - without forcing a login?

Thanks, Donal

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870309/refresh-user-cookie-ticket-in-asp-net-core-identity
Appears to be possible if you use the SignInManager.RefreshSignInAsync method.

Comment: This response also might answer your question. Instead of changing the value in the controller, this person is doing it on each cookie validation.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073362/replace-value-in-cookie-asp-net-core-1-0
Let me know if neither of these articles answer your question, and I can investigate further.

Comment: Thanks Kevin but we are not using ASP.Net Core Identity - using OpenIdConnect/Cookies and ADAL.I'll have to study the linked posts a bit more but I don't think they are applicable.